# Loop through a python list and get a 1 or 0 for a match result

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a question, I tried to search the forum and see if there is something that can help me but unfortunately I couldn't so here it is:
Currently I'm using our AD system and check through that list to see if a user exists and depending on that give them access or not

```
users = [AD user list]
for user in users:
    if user == "user x":
        print "you are in"
     else:
        print "denied"
```

This works great and all but I want to know if I can make this a bit more efficient, so say if the "user x" is the 10th in the list, this code will print "denied" 9 times before it prints "you are in".

Is it possible to somehow look into the list first and if the string match is in there give a 1 and if not a 0? This way when I print this I get either a 1 or a 0.

Hope my question was clear and I provided enough details. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: uppercase `Print` without parentheses? What python version is it?

Comment: Sure. A simple way to do so is set a boolean flag to false before your loop. If the condition is true in the loop- set the flag to true. After the loop check the flag. if true, print you are in. Else, print you are denied.

Comment: why `Print`, it should be `print` or `print()`.

Comment: `print('you are in' if 'user x' in users else 'denied')`

Comment: Ternary operators arent always the best. @AndriyMaletsky

Comment: nothing is always the best :D

Comment: Ahh... I figured I meessed something up.. I was typing that on my phone and figured skip the ()... Sorry guys 

Comment: Please show the code that queries the AD. These things can be done directly in the AD query (server side). Fetching the entire group contents and checking for matches on the client side is wasteful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the `in` operator. For example:

```
users = ['john', 'adam', 'susan']
exists = 'john' in users      # will be true
exists2 = 'robert' in users     # will be false

# for 1 or 0 output
exists = int(exists)
exists2 = int(exists2)
```

Comment: You should really make `users` a set.

Comment: @chrisz "I" would. But OP is using a list.

Comment: OP wants output `1` or `0`. So wrap `int()` around.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you can use .index here instead of a full for loop.

```
try:
    users.index('user x')
    print 'You are in!' # assuming you are using python 2

catch ValueError:
    print 'Denied!'
```

Using `in` is also an option.

```
if 'user x' in users:
    print 'You are in!'

else:
    print 'Denied!'
```